# res.render for routes on page reload?

Tags: express, angular-ui-router, mean, ejs

(Using MEAN with UI Router)

The following code sends a json response for the route defined. This works fine when the template is rendered with UI Router; however, if I reload the page, because the response only contains json, I am left with an empty page rendering no html, only the json response.

```
router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.populate('comments', function(err, post) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

Assuming this is a standard issue, how can I best allow this page to res.render('index') when the page is reloaded and respond with the json response? Should I,

- Create a separate route for the json response which is called as a post promise with UI Router
- Have the /posts/:post route simply respond with res.render('index')?

Thank you for any responses, not sure what the usual practise is for such issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to find a working solution to this due to many of the examples online having different directory structures. I placed a catch all at the end of my routes so that url requests to any UI Router states would not be met with a 404, but instead always return the index.html file.

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Then I added prefixes to my express routes, e.g. /api/posts/:post etc. Apparently express routes should not clash with any of the angular defined routes. Thanks to NormySan on reddit for informing me about this.